# Resume from an error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, constructor, onerror

Before I get yelled at for trying something so reckless, let me tell you that I wouldn't do this in real life and it's an academic question.

Suppose I'm writing a library and I want my object to be able to make up methods as they are needed.

For example if you wanted to call a `.slice()` method, and I didn't have one then the `window.onerror` handler would fire it for me

Anyway I played around with this [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shkx7/)

```
window.onerror = function(e) {
    var method = /'(.*)'$/.exec(e)[1];
    console.log(method); // slice
    return Array.prototype[method].call(this, arguments); // not even almost gonna work 
};

var myLib = function(a, b, c) {
    if (this == window) return new myLib(a, b, c);
    this[1] = a; this[2] = b; this[3] = c;
    return this;
};

var obj = myLib(1,2,3);

console.log(obj.slice(1));
```

Also (maybe I should start a new question) can I change my constructor to take an unspecified amount of args?

```
var myLib = function(a, b, c) {
    if (this == window) return new myLib.apply(/* what goes here? */, arguments);
    this[1] = a; this[2] = b; this[3] = c;
    return this;
};
```

BTW I know I can load my objects with

```
['slice', 'push', '...'].forEach(function() { myLib.prototype[this] = [][this]; });
```

That's not what I'm looking for

Comment: it sounds like you're thinking about javascript ["pollyfills" or "shims"](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/)

Comment: incidentally it's usually more elegant and reliable to catch exceptions with a try-catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you were asking an academic question, I suppose browser compatibility is not an issue. If it's indeed not, I'd like to introduce harmony proxies for this. `onerror` is not a very good practice as it's just a event raised if *somewhere* an error occurs. It should, if ever, only be used as a last resort. (I know you said you don't use it anyway, but `onerror` is just not very developer-friendly.)

Basically, proxies enable you to intercept most of the fundamental operations in JavaScript - most notably getting any property which is useful here. In this case, you could intercept the process of getting `.slice`.

Note that proxies are "black holes" by default. They do not correspond to any object (e.g. setting a property on a proxy just calls the `set` trap (interceptor); the actual storing you have to do yourself). But there is a "forwarding handler" available that routes everything through to a normal object (or an instance of course), so that the proxy behaves as a normal object. By extending the handler (in this case, the `get` part), you can quite easily route `Array.prototype` methods through as follows.

So, whenever *any* property (with name `name`) is being fetched, the code path is as follows:

1. Try returning `inst[name]`.
2. Otherwise, try returning a function which applies `Array.prototype[name]` on the instance with the given arguments to this function.
3. Otherwise, just return `undefined`.

If you want to play around with proxies, you can use a recent version of V8, for example in a nightly build of Chromium (make sure to run as `chrome --js-flags="--harmony"`). Again, proxies are not available for "normal" usage because they're relatively new, change a lot of the fundamental parts of JavaScript and are in fact not officially specified yet (still drafts).

This is a simple diagram of how it goes like (`inst` is actually the proxy which the instance has been wrapped into). Note that it only illustrates *getting* a property; all other operations are simply passed through by the proxy because of the unmodified forwarding handler.

[image: proxy diagram]

The proxy code could be as follows:

```
function Test(a, b, c) {
  this[0] = a;
  this[1] = b;
  this[2] = c;

  this.length = 3; // needed for .slice to work
}

Test.prototype.foo = "bar";

Test = (function(old) { // replace function with another function
                        // that returns an interceptor proxy instead
                        // of the actual instance
  return function() {
    var bind = Function.prototype.bind,
        slice = Array.prototype.slice,

        args = slice.call(arguments),

        // to pass all arguments along with a new call:
        inst = new(bind.apply(old, [null].concat(args))),
        //                          ^ is ignored because of `new`
        //                            which forces `this`

        handler = new Proxy.Handler(inst); // create a forwarding handler
                                           // for the instance

    handler.get = function(receiver, name) { // overwrite `get` handler
      if(name in inst) { // just return a property on the instance
        return inst[name];
      }

      if(name in Array.prototype) { // otherwise try returning a function
                                    // that calls the appropriate method
                                    // on the instance
        return function() {
          return Array.prototype[name].apply(inst, arguments);
        };
      }
    };

    return Proxy.create(handler, Test.prototype);
  };
})(Test);

var test = new Test(123, 456, 789),
    sliced = test.slice(1);

console.log(sliced);               // [456, 789]
console.log("2" in test);          // true
console.log("2" in sliced);        // false
console.log(test instanceof Test); // true
                                   // (due to second argument to Proxy.create)
console.log(test.foo);             // "bar"
```

---

The forwarding handler is available at [the official harmony wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxy_defaulthandler).

```
Proxy.Handler = function(target) {
  this.target = target;
};

Proxy.Handler.prototype = {
  // Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proxy, name) -> pd | undefined
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(name) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.target, name);
    if (desc !== undefined) { desc.configurable = true; }
    return desc;
  },

  // Object.getPropertyDescriptor(proxy, name) -> pd | undefined
  getPropertyDescriptor: function(name) {
    var desc = Object.getPropertyDescriptor(this.target, name);
    if (desc !== undefined) { desc.configurable = true; }
    return desc;
  },

  // Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proxy) -> [ string ]
  getOwnPropertyNames: function() {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.target);
  },

  // Object.getPropertyNames(proxy) -> [ string ]
  getPropertyNames: function() {
    return Object.getPropertyNames(this.target);
  },

  // Object.defineProperty(proxy, name, pd) -> undefined
  defineProperty: function(name, desc) {
    return Object.defineProperty(this.target, name, desc);
  },

  // delete proxy[name] -> boolean
  delete: function(name) { return delete this.target[name]; },

  // Object.{freeze|seal|preventExtensions}(proxy) -> proxy
  fix: function() {
    // As long as target is not frozen, the proxy won't allow itself to be fixed
    if (!Object.isFrozen(this.target)) {
      return undefined;
    }
    var props = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.target).forEach(function(name) {
      props[name] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.target, name);
    }.bind(this));
    return props;
  },

  // == derived traps ==

  // name in proxy -> boolean
  has: function(name) { return name in this.target; },

  // ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(proxy, name) -> boolean
  hasOwn: function(name) { return ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(this.target, name); },

  // proxy[name] -> any
  get: function(receiver, name) { return this.target[name]; },

  // proxy[name] = value
  set: function(receiver, name, value) {
   this.target[name] = value;
   return true;
  },

  // for (var name in proxy) { ... }
  enumerate: function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var name in this.target) { result.push(name); };
    return result;
  },

  // Object.keys(proxy) -> [ string ]
  keys: function() { return Object.keys(this.target); }
};
```